# boto s3 write doesnt work but read file works

Tags: amazon-s3, boto

Hi I am using boto to write files to an S3 bucket. I recently deleted an EC2 instance and started a new one with new key pair. I can now read the files from the bucket but when I try to write files it fails with no errors. I can see the files in the bucket. Here is the code:

```
conn = S3Connection()

bucket = conn.get_bucket('my-bucket')
keylist = bucket.list()
k = Key(bucket)

def upload_file():
  # Get the name of the uploaded files
  uploaded_files = request.files.getlist("file[]")

  current_date = time.strftime("%x").split("/")[0]+time.strftime("%x").split("/")[1]+time.strftime("%x").split("/")[2]
  filenames = []

  for file in uploaded_files:
    # Check if the file is one of the allowed types/extensions
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):

        # Make the filename safe, remove unsupported chars
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)

        file_contents = file.read()
        k.key = current_date + "/" + file.filename
        print "uploading files now "
        k.set_contents_from_string(file_contents)
```

I am not sure if this is because of the new key pair. It does provide read access though. But write doesn't happen. Is it because of the new instance? FYI it works perfectly in localhost.

Comment: What do you mean by "it works perfectly in localhost"? Keypairs are used to login to an EC2 instance, they are not used for API calls. Rather, check the **role** that is assigned to the instance, which is used to assign IAM credentials to software running on the instance.

Comment: Are you getting a return value from the `k.set_contents_from_string()` call? You might want to try getting a new key (`k = Key(bucket)`) for each separate file rather than re-using the existing values.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, "it works perfectly in localhost" show the mistake made.

In fact : 
For S3 connection, unless you define a passwordless policies to allow specific host to write the data,  the obvious method is using your IAM credential connect to S3.  Thus, in your local machine, it will works, because boto3 just get the credential and config from your aws access folder.

Now you have 2 choices.

1. Dirty way : Create another IAM user that has rights to write to S3 only, set it up on EC2 instance that host the application
2. Configure your S3 bucket policies, add restriction to write from your EC2 instance IP address. Because EC2 inside VPC can connect to S3 directly through endpoint.  Check out Bucket policy setting here : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-iam-policies.html